# Better method for Rewrite URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Which method is better for rewrite URLs

(a). Using htaccess file and use regular expression in it, for rewrite rule

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^threads/(\d+)*$ ./thread.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ ./search.php?query=$1
```

OR

(b).
 use htacess file for just redirect every url to `index.php` and then use  PHP for further redirection.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

 RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

and after that every url can be handle by `index.php` using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and we can use `require()` statement for load particular file

Which method is better on the basis of security and speed ?

Answer (score 0):

This method is more perfect, use the below codes for your .htaccess file, and also define your directories which you want access in your scripts such as: js, css or upload folders

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|**data**|**live**|**css**|**js**|**images**).
```

if you want to put your script inside the folder you have to define the folder name before /index.php at second last statement such us

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ **anyFolderName**/index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Make sure you didn't put any extra space, letter or enter otherwise rewrite model will not execute.

Note: and also make sure you run/check the rewrite_module from your server/apache/apache modules/rewrite_module.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
# you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
# If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
# let it as it is
RewriteBase /

# Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

# Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets)

# No rewriting
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements. If you have those php files already created then refactoring of first .htaccess into a single rule like this should work fine:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```